# pandas read csv giving creating incorrect columns

Tags: pandas, dataframe, numpy, csv

I am using `pandas` to read a `csv file`

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('file_name.csv', "ISO-8859-1")
```

Op:

```
col1,col2,col3
"sample1","sample2","sample3"
```

but the `DF` is just creating `1 column` instead of the `5` it is supposed to create. I checked the `csv` and its fine.

Any suggestions on why this could be happening will be useful.

Comment: Is this **all** of your code? It creates 3 columns with one row here.

Comment: @hd1 yes, but the problem is it creates ```only 1 column``` instead of ```3``` where the ```col_names``` and ```col_entries``` are merged into that ```1``` column

Comment: I doubt the example you have is the real CSV. I would bet for an incorrect formatting. Maybe unbalanced quotes? `"abc,def, ghi"` would evaluate as one field. Please provide the real header.

Comment: why is your 2nd argument `"ISO-8859-1"`? the second argument is the `sep` /  delimiter. That's leading to your single column

Comment: @AsishM. you were right. my bad. please post it as the answer and I can accept it.